# JavaScript Disabled textarea не работает

Tags: javascript, html, native

Мне нужно, чтобы textarea был disabled, но все методы, которые я нашел - не помогли

```
<textarea id="textarea-message" type="text" placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
```

Пытался через `.setAttribute()` поставить disabled - не получилось

Пытался даже так

```
let aa = document.querySelector("#textarea-message");
aa.disabled = true;
```

Не помогает все равно.
Как исправить код?

Мне нужен именно нативный JS, а не jQuery

Comment: Проверил `aa.disabled = true` — вполне работает

Comment: `aa.setAttribute("disabled", "")`

Answer (score 1):

Странно конечно попробуйте тогда как [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_disabled.asp)

```
document.getElementById("myTextarea").disabled = true;
```

В принципе там тоже самое только описано стандартами. Предполагаю что это не весь ваш код и где-то за кулисами у вас есть обратное.

Загрузите/запустите скрипт после рендера документа чтоб сработало когда контрол будет на странице

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
  let aa = document.getElementById("textarea-message");
  aa.disabled = true;
}
```

Сделал так и заработало. Видимо я немножечко дурачок...

Comment: Нет просто вы запускали скрипт когда не было этого элемента в документе